# In affter effect cs 6, I don't know why i cannot use mask with effects

Tags: after-effects

I try to edit a video clip, like a steady cam and slow motion, using a mask and Time Warp in after effect.

But, whenever i select any effect in Effect menu of a menu bar, the mask is not working.

Can i use a mask and effect at the same time?

or, i have to use pre-composition where effect is applied, and then mask, such pre-comp?

plz help me.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Can you post a relevant screenshot or two?

Comment: Yes, precomp your layer and apply a mask on the composition instead.